# Lucene.net - query returning unwanted documents

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

All of my Lucene.net (2.9.2) documents have two fields:

- categoryid
- bodytext

`bodytext` is the default field, and is where all of the document's text is stored (using `Field.Store.NO , Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS` ).

`categoryid` is just a numeric field stored as text: `Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`

When this query is executed, it only returns documents with that category ID: `categoryid:1`

However when I perform this query: `categoryid:1 foo bar` it returns documents from other categories other than 1.

Why is this? And how can I force it to respect the original `categoryid:N` query term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to require all words entered to be present in your matched documents?

```cs
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "bodytext", analyzer);

// This ensures that all terms are required.
queryParser.DefaultOperator = QueryParser.Operator.AND;

var query = queryParser.Parse("categoryid:1 foo bar");
// query = "+categoryid:1 +bodytext:foo +bodytext:bar"
```

Comment: Is the default in Lucene to use the OR operator instead of AND?

Comment: @David, precisely. It handles misspelt words better; causing them to be ignored instead of an empty search result.

Comment: In version 2.9 the syntax is slightly different: `queryParser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR)`.